# Where it's marked that a "/data/app/i" have to appear in launcher?

Tags: installation, launcher, recovery-mode

I have some apps who have important data in it. And now they don't appear in the launcher, but they still in /data/app. Do you know what to do to make appear an app from /data/app in the launcher ? Like manually install an app, without the Android Installer

Comment: Did you disable them or at least their MAIN activity? Which launcher are you using? Since when did they disappear?  Have you tried launching them through QuickShortcutMaker? In fact, have you fully ascertained that they are still installed?

Comment: I haven't disable them, what's the MAIN activity ?
I use the default one, OP Launcher.
They dissapear since a ROM reinstallation.
Quick doesn't show them.
The app store doesn't let me reinstall them, so

Comment: Had you installed them to the SD card maybe? Note this doesn't contradict their appearing in `/data/app` as only parts are moved to the card then. Further, which Android version? If you use an SD card, do you use [tag:adoptable-storage]?

Comment: I haven't SD slot.
Marshmallow

Comment: My question is related to this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16277422/android-install-failed-uid-changed but there isn't solutions to get the app data